# how to get Global schema for two specific sobject salesforce apex?

Tags: apex

How to get global schema for two objects in salesforce

This code is working for all objects::::

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType ObjectSchema = schemaMap.get(AllObjectsList); 
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = ObjectSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Comment: Faiz got your ans?

Comment: No Ratan, not for only two specific values.

Comment: Hey Faiz.. Can you tell me what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Sure Ratan.. My requirement was to get the global schema details only for two sObejcts (Lead & Camp) in single hit, I had syntax for one or all sObjects, and i was searching for two objects.

Comment: then use `Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();` and `Campaign.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();` .. There is no way to get at a time you can get 2 sobjects... else you can describe 2times and return for both add into a map.

Comment: Let me know if you need this then I will update my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO If your Sobject is dynamic then Assign the name to a string..

get the sobject Type using `Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName)`..

Then describe the fields..

```
String typeName = 'Account';

Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(typeName);

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = targetType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
system.debug(fieldMap);
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if could add some useful comments to your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use sobject token like `Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();` because `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` is heavy call as compared to the token.